# How can I export the best classifier from my code to a model for real future usage?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, predictive-modeling, model-selection

```
# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('processed.csv', header=0, engine='python')

# Pre-processing the data
# Define X,Y features
X = df.drop('Class', axis=1)
Y = df['Class']

# prepare configuration for cross validation test harness
seed = 3
# prepare models
models = [('LR', LogisticRegression()), ('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()), ('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()),
          ('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()), ('NB', GaussianNB()), ('SVM', SVC())]
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)

# Saving the model for usage in the Heroku app
joblib.dump(bestmodel, 'model.pkl')
print("Model Saved.")

# boxplot algorithm comparison
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()
```

Working Update

```
# Pre-processing the data
# Define X,y features
X = df.drop('Class', axis=1)
Y = df['Class']
# prepare configuration for cross validation test harness
seed = 7
# prepare models
models = [('LR', LogisticRegression()), ('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()), ('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()),
          ('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()), ('NB', GaussianNB()), ('SVM', SVC())]
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'
current_score = 0
best_score = 0
best_model = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
    current_score = cv_results.mean()
    if current_score > best_score:
        best_score = current_score
        best_model = model

# boxplot algorithm comparison
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()

# Saving the model for usage in the Heroku app
joblib.dump(best_model, 'model.pkl')
print("Model Saved.")
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you need help with? You can save a scikit-learn model using either pickle or joblib ([as mentioned in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html)), for which you already have the code in the example you're sharing.

Comment: Yes but how would I format joblib.dump to use the model with the best accuracy automatically?

Comment: You can simply add some logic that keeps track of the best score and best model, if the current score in your for loop is higher than the current best score set the best model to the current model in your loop.

Comment: That seems to of done the trick! I have updated my post to reflect the change. Can you confirm with me that this is the proper way do this code wise and that I am not missing anything? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The logic seems completely fine.

In your place, I would save all the model's performances inside a dictionary to keep track and use any of them in case I need them.

```
seed = 7
# prepare models
models = [('LR', LogisticRegression()), ('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()), ('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()),
          ('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()), ('NB', GaussianNB()), ('SVM', SVC())]
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'
models_dict = {}
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
    models_dict[name] = {"binary":model,"avg_performance":cv_results.mean(),"std_perfirmance":cv_results.std()}

best_model_dict = list(models_dict.values())[np.argmax([x["avg_performance"] for x in list(models_dict.values())])]

best_model = best_model_dict["binary"].fit(X,y)
    


# boxplot algorithm comparison
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Algorithm Comparison')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()

# Saving the model for usage in the Heroku app
joblib.dump(best_model, 'model.pkl')
print("Model Saved.")
```

Comment: I now get this error when I try to use the model on my app.py Heroku file     `sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This DecisionTreeClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.`

Comment: I have updated my post to include my app.py file which is the one receiving the error

Comment: Are you still there? :D

Comment: This is because your best model is not still fitted. you need to add best_model.fit(X,y) before saving the pickle. check my updated answer